# Liquibase modifysql tag with sql tag in same changeset not working

Tags: liquibase

> liquibase: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting
>   with element 'sql'. One of
>   '{"http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":modifySql}' is
>   expected.

Getting an error for this changeset

```
<changeSet id="18.7.0.1-1-userTable" author="so">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <tableExists tableName="USER_CURRENT"/>
        </not>
    </preConditions>
    <createTable tableName="USER_CURRENT">
        <column name="name" type="VARCHAR(20)">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" primaryKeyName="name"/>
        </column>

    </createTable>
    <modifySql dbms="mysql">
        <append value=" PARTITION BY KEY() PARTITIONS 16"/>
    </modifySql>
    <modifySql dbms="oracle">
        <append value=" ORGANIZATION INDEX PARTITION BY HASH (name) PARTITIONS 16 PARALLEL 4"/>
    </modifySql>
    <sql>GRANT SELECT ON USER_CURRENT TO 'reportsUser'@'%';</sql>       
</changeSet>
```

Comment: Hi Bhadra, welcome to SO. Please format and proofread your questions. Also look here to learn how to ask properly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The reason for it is that you can't have `sql` after `modifySql` tag inside the `changeSet`.
You'll have either to put `sql` before `modifySql` or just to separate them into different `changeSets`.

It follows from `dbchangelog-3.1.xsd`.